# Spring-data-jpa LazyInitializationException: no Session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

i have a problem with Spring-data-jpa project.

**JavaConfig file**

...

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("it.myproject.data")
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ, proxyTargetClass = true)
@PropertySource("classpath:/it/myproject/application.properties")
public
        class DBConfig
{

    private static final
            String PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = "entitymanager.packages.to.scan";
    @Resource
    private
            Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public
            DataSource dataSource()
    {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public
            EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory()
    {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager()
    {
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

To test that all works fine I created this method

```
@Transactional
    public
            void doIt()
    {
        PersonDTO created = new PersonDTO();
        created.setId(null);
        created.setFirstName("Pluto");
        created.setLastName("Paperino");
        Person pippo= repositoryPersonService.create(created);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            BookDTO bookDTO = new BookDTO();
            bookDTO.setTitle("Fantasia" + i);
            bookDTO.setPerson(pippo);
            repositoryBookService.create(bookDTO);
        }
        repositoryPersonService.findAll().stream().forEach((Person t) -> {
            System.out.println(t.getBooks());
        });
    }
```

My entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "persons")
public
        class Person
        implements Serializable
{

    private static final
            long serialVersionUID = 198765467898765L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private
            Long id;
    @Column(name = "creation_time", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private
            Date creationTime;
    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private
            String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private
            String lastName;
    @Column(name = "modification_time", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private
            Date modificationTime;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private
            List<Book> books;
    @Version
    private
            long version = 0;
```

But i received this error message:

2014-04-09 12:31:54 TRACE LazyInitializationException:53 - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: it.myproject.data.person.Person.books, could not initialize proxy - no Session
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: it.myproject.data.person.Person.books, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Can you help me?
Thank you

Comment: Do you run into the same issue if you just iterate through `repositoryPersonService.findAll()` normally (i.e. without using a stream)?

Answer (score 4):

Solved. I removed "(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ, proxyTargetClass = true)" from configuration and now it works fine. Thaks guys!

Before->

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("it.myproject.data")
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ, proxyTargetClass = true)
@PropertySource("classpath:/it/myproject/application.properties")
```

Now ->

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("it.myproject.data")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:/it/myproject/application.properties")
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `@Transactional` is not working, as `repositoryPersonService.findAll()` is returning a collection of detached entities. Then when trying to loop through those entities and access lazy initialized collections, we run into `LazyInitializationException`.

To confirm this, try putting a breakpoint in the method where `findAll` is called, and see if the transactional aspect is being applied or not.

To apply `@Transactional` to the test method, see that it's a Spring bean caught by a component scan (using `ComponentScan("some.package")` annotation).